# Create a qstate in qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

If I have a simple state machine like that

```
  switch(state)
    {
    case state_1:
      doSomething();
    state = state_2;
    break;
    case state_2:
    doSomething_2();
state = state_finished;
    break;
    }
```

how would I convert this simple state machine into qstate with transitions ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please start with reading the excellent documentation of the Qt State Machine Framework at http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/statemachine-api.html. Then try what you learned and if you still have problems first read this (http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then edit your Question to show what you have tried and what specifically does not work.

Comment: @Mailerdaimon I read the documentation but I couldn't make the state machine above to qtstatemachine :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be for example something like this:

```
TestClass test_class;
QStateMachine machine;

QState *state_1 = new QState(&machine);
QObject::connect(state_1, SIGNAL(entered()), &test_class, SLOT(doSomething1()));

QState *state_2 = new QState(&machine);
QObject::connect(state_2, SIGNAL(entered()), &test_class, SLOT(doSomething2()));

QFinalState *state_finished = new QFinalState(&machine);
TestClassFinishedTransition *finished_transition = 
                                new TestClassFinishedTransition(&test_class);
finished_transition->setTargetState(state_finished);
state_2->addTransition(finished_transition);

machine.setInitialState(state_1);
machine.start();
```

TestClass would be `QObject` based class.

I hope this piece of code helps you to get started in understanding the concept. However, you have to read the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/statemachine-api.html) carefully and go through examples provided by Qt.

Comment: Short Note: Question is tagged Qt4 and you linked the documentation to Qt5.